# xcode - moving tableview origin

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a iPad prototype.
I have a view controller which contains 3 table views, split equally as columns under a segmented control, on selecting one of the segments i want to hide the tableview in the center and share the available space equally between the table views on the left and right. how can i achieve this.
I just started working on objective C so any help would be great! 
i am using xcode 4.6 so auto layout is selected on the view controller by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two distinct layouts that cannot be handled with the same set of auto layout constraints, the trick is to have a second set of lower-priority constraints whose priority you increase when switching to the alternate UI layout (in your case, hiding the center table view). You'll normally also have to decrease the priority of one or more constraints that were needed for the original layout.

When layouting your UI, you'll first want to set up the constraints so they work well for the layout with all three table views. Then add constraints with a lower priority for the "two table views" case. In your controller, create IBOutlet properties for those lower-priority constraints, and for all constraints that will prevent them from working. Connect the outlets to the constraints in your UI.

You'll then do the following when switching to two table views:

```
[centerTableView setHidden:YES];

// lower the priority for all constraints that don't apply for two table views
[someConstraint setPriority: NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow];
// ...

// increase the priority for all previously low-priority constraints
[someOtherConstraint setPriority:NSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh];
// ...
```